# How do I fetch a contact's email address?

Tags: php, oauth-2.0

I am using the contact example from the Google OAuth API. I am not getting the contact's email address. I need contact's email address for sending an invitation request. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: For someone to be able to answer your question, you're going to need to provide a lot more detail - *relevant* code, for instance. We can't tell you why you're not getting the email without seeing how you're trying it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to request access to the scope: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email. Once you have permission, then you send an authorized request to: https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo. You will receive back a response with the email address:

```
{
 "email": "<myname>@gmail.com",
 "verified_email": true
}
```

NOTE: If you want to access the rest of the profile, you need to add to the scope with: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile. Then the same request will return the full profile with email address:

```
{
 "id": "<myID>",
 "email": "<myemail>@gmail.com",
 "verified_email": true,
 "name": "<my name>",
 "given_name": "<first>",
 "family_name": "<last>",
 "link": "https://plus.google.com/<myID>",
 "picture": "https://lh4.googleusercontent.com/<pic link>/photo.jpg",
 "gender": "male",
 "birthday": "<YYYY-MM-DD>",
 "locale": "en-US"
}
```